# argmin for least square + convex penalization

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to solve the following exercice :

Let F be such that $F(\theta) = \| Y - X \theta \|_2^2 + h(\theta)$ where $h : \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$

Let $\theta_1$ and  $\theta_2$ two minimizers of $F$.
Prove that $X \theta_1 = X\theta_2$ and $h(\theta_1) = h(\theta_2)$.

We know that $argmin F$ is a convex set, in particular, for all $t \in [0,1],  \theta_2 -t(\theta_2 - \theta_1)$ in is $argmin F$

It came that $\phi : t \mapsto F(\theta_2 -t(\theta_2 - \theta_1))$ is constant and we have that $h(\theta_1) + \|Y -X\theta_1\|_2^2 = h(\theta_2) + \|Y -X\theta_2\|_2^2$

But it is not enough to conclude and the solution is probably to derivate $\phi$ ($\phi' = 0$ and $\phi'' = 0$ too).

I'm not sure to know how to procede because there is no further assumption on $h$ so chain rule may be difficult to apply.

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1):

Take two minimizers $\theta_1,\theta_2$. Then also $\frac12(\theta_1+\theta_2)$ is a minimizer. If $X\theta_1 \ne X \theta_2$ then
by strict convexity of $\|\cdot\|_2^2$, this implies
$$
\frac12 \|Y - X(\frac12(\theta_1+\theta_2))\|^2
<\frac12\left[ \frac12 \|Y - X\theta_1\|^2 + \frac12 \|Y - X\theta_2\|^2 \right].
$$
Now add to this the following inequality
$$
h(\frac12(\theta_1+\theta_2)) \le \frac12h(\theta_1) + \frac12h(\theta_2),
$$
so that $F(\frac12(\theta_1+\theta_2))< \frac12 F(\theta_1) + \frac12 F(\theta_2)$, which is impossible.